# The lights object data properties has vanished

Tags: properties

Using Blender 3.6.3 initially, just installed 3.6.4

At some point I realised that all Object data properties have gone meaning im unable to make further changes to the lights in the scene.

Tried many things including updating to 3.6.4, which resolved problems in the past.

Clearly I'm new to Blender but I don't think I touched anything I shouldn't.
[image]

Comment: Even for a new blend file? Switching to Workbench Renderer the light properties are quite limited, but even there you should be able to switch between light types ...

Comment: Ah Good point. In both workbench and Eevee light type returns but not in Cycles. Thanks though

Comment: So ... it can be a bug  ... so check it if reported on Bug Tracker ... or isn't it cross version issue? Have you tried a new file wit File > Defaults > Factory Setting?

Comment: Brilliant. just reset to factory and reopened file and there they are. Many many thanks vklidu. Oh, how/where would i find Bug Tracker.

Comment: Great it worked for you. If that helped it could be some addon conflict ... to report a bug on top row go to Help > Report a Bug :) Just if Factory Settings worked for don't post it as a bug since the problem lays at some third party code. You should test what is causing this issue specifically (what makes th e properties hidden) and than try to contact someone specific.

Comment: Thnks. It hasn't happened since and so leave things as they are to see if it happens again and then turn off add ons to see if i can locate the problem.